# How can I add a transition to a lightning utility icon?

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-design-system

I need to add a transition to a  lightning utility icon `<lightning-icon>`. I can't find any docs or solutions to this. Does anyone know how or does anyone have any good articles or docs relating to this?

Comment: This will be hard because of the shadow dom lwc enforces. Where exactly is your component used? In Salesforce or in Experience Site?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure about the `<lightning-icon>` but you can apply transition to the blue print of slds-icon. Here are two examples.

*Example 1 - In this simple example, on hover the Icon will grow bigger.*

*HTML*

```
<span class="slds-icon_container slds-icon-utility-announcement" title="Description of icon when needed">
    <svg class="slds-icon slds-icon-text-default myIcon" aria-hidden="true">
        <use xlink:href="/_slds/icons/standard-sprite/svg/symbols.svg#announcement"></use>
    </svg>
    <span class="slds-assistive-text">Description of icon when needed</span>
</span>
```

*CSS*

```
.myIcon {
    transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
}

.myIcon:hover {
    transform: scale(2);
}
```

*Screen grab:*

[image]

*Example 2 - In this simple example, the icon rotates itself continuously.*

*HTML*

```
<span class="slds-icon_container slds-icon-utility-announcement" title="Description of icon when needed">
    <svg class="slds-icon slds-icon-text-default myIcon" aria-hidden="true">
        <use xlink:href="/_slds/icons/utility-sprite/svg/symbols.svg#refresh"></use>
    </svg>
    <span class="slds-assistive-text">Description of icon when needed</span>
</span>
```

*CSS*

```
.myIcon {
    animation: rotation 2s infinite linear;
}

@keyframes rotation {
    from {
        transform: rotate(0deg);
    }
    to {
        transform: rotate(359deg);
    }
}
```

*Screen grab:*

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply :) I eventually went for a solution like this, just would be nice if there was a styling hook or something I could use with the <lightning-icon> element